# Screenshot always turns out dimmed on MIUI

Tags: android-11, miui, screenshots

When I take a screenshot on my Android Smartphone, it always turns out dimmed. For example, if a pixel is completely white (i.e. `#ffffff` in color) it is light gray in the screenshot. See the example screenshot below for reference. As you can see, all the bright areas are light gray instead of white, when they should be white. What can I do to fix this problem?

Additional note: The dimming is not permanent, it happens only when creating a screenshot for the time of the screenshot and vanishes right after.
**Moreover, the same erroneous effect occurs when taking a *recording* of the screen *for the whole time of recording*!**.

###### System Specs:

- MIUI Version 12.5.7
- Android Version 11

[image]

Comment: @Robert The image shows a partial screenshot, not a photo.

Comment: So if it is a screenshot we can exclude hardware defects on the display and problems with the brightness control of the display(e.g. because of defect ambient light sensor). One possibility would be a "night" or "red-shift" app that always draws an semi-transparent overlay above every app that is displayed. Check your app list.

Comment: @Robert I don't have such an app on my phone. And do note: The dimming is not permanent: It happens **right when making the screenshot** and vanishes right after too. I.e. the dimming is only **triggered when making the screenshot** and for the time of it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself: Navigate to `Settings` > `Display` > `More Dark mode options` then disable `Adjust text and backgrounds automatically`.

[image]